# get image from mySQL to listview Android

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

I want to get an image from my database mySQL to show in listview (image + text listview)

my code :

```
       public void cek(){

           String url_select = "http://10.0.2.2/BloodGlucose/selectDoctor.php";

           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

           //parameter
           ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

           try {
              //add parameter
               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

             HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
             HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

             //read content
             InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
             BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

             String content = "";
             String line = "";

             while((line = read.readLine())!=null){
                content += line;
             }

             Log.d("ADBUG", "content: "+content);


             //json
             if(!content.equals("null")){




                try {
                   JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(content);
                   for(int i=0;i<jArr.length();i++){
                      JSONObject jObj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                      String id = jObj.getString("_id");
                      String name = jObj.getString("name");
                      String dateofbirth = jObj.getString("dateofbirth");
                      String phone = jObj.getString("telp");
                      String address = jObj.getString("clinicaddress");
                      String file = jObj.getString("file");
                      String uname = jObj.getString("username_doctor");
                      String lulusan = jObj.getString("lulusan");
                      String clinicname = jObj.getString("clinicname");

                      names.add(name);
                      date.add(dateofbirth);
                      telp.add(phone);      
                      clinic.add(address);
                      usernamedoctor.add(uname);
                      namaklinik.add(clinicname);
                      graduate.add(lulusan);



                   }



setListAdapter(new DoctorArrayAdapter(this, names)); 

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

             }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
```

DoctorArrayAdapter code:

```
package research.android.bloodglucose;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import research.android.bloodglucose.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DoctorArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;

    public DoctorArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_row, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = names;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.DoctorName);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        textView.setText(values.get(position));

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values.get(position);

        System.out.println(s);

        /*if (s.equals("WindowsMobile")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windowsmobile_logo);
        } else if (s.equals("iOS")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
        } else if (s.equals("Blackberry")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
        }*/

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

is there any something wrong with my code? because the image didn't show, it's only the text, thank you very much

Comment: It seems you're getting image from `URL` only not from `Database`

Comment: wow, that's sooo much code to analize - next time try to extract important parts... :)

Comment: I'm sorry for that cause I can't find the problem, here's the updated important parts (i think)

Comment: @SpK because I've hosting my database so I want to get the image by URL based on image I've uploaded before :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handy, You should create a class that extends from `ArrayAdapter`, then you implement the method `getView` to tell your list what to do on each item (add the image and the text).

check this link [Android listview example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

(the Custom ArrayAdapter example)

(And one tip, your error part comes from building a listview not from fetching the data from MySQL so remove this part from your question it's misleading)

This is a function to get the image having its url path

```
public static Bitmap getURLImage(String path)
{

    try
    {
        URL aURL = new URL(path);
        final URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                conn.getInputStream());
        final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        return bm;
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {   
        Log.w("ERROR", "Error " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

then you do (you should call it from a thread, because since android 4.0 you're not allowed to make a network connection from the main thread, This is the part that should be added in `getView`):

```
    new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        //mBitmap is an attirbute
                        mBitmap = getRemoteImage(link);
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(COMPLETE);

                    } finally {

                    }
                };
            };



/**
in your handler u set the image to the bitmap that you fetched
*/
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(new Callback() {

            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response, do you have example for extends class from arrrayadapter? I'm sorry for ask so much question, I'm newbie for android

Comment: Yes its in the link, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/. go to it and search for "Custom ArrayAdapter example". It's exactly what you need

Comment: thank you, but can you show me how to get image from URL? because at the example, the image is in the drawable, I've been updated the question, thank you very much

Comment: I'm not quite understand. the URL is "http://10.0.2.2/BloodGlucose/img/"+uname+".jpg"; and the "uname" is from username which i get from my database using JSON code, how can u combine your code with JSON code which use to get uname from database, thank you, sorry for asking too much question. and also, I put your code in DoctorArrayAddapter.java right?

Comment: now doctorArrayAdapter is extending `ArrayAdapter<String>`, You can make it extend `ArrayAdapter<UrCustomObject>`, with `UrCustomObject` containing 2 attributes, the name and the url string. `values` should then be an `ArrayList<UrCustomObject>`. Yes the whole code to get the image can be in `DoctorArrayAdapter`

Comment: public DoctorArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names,  String aURL) {
  super(context, R.layout.list_row, names);
  this.context = context;
  this.values = names;
  aURL = "http://10.0.2.2/BloodGlucose/img/";
  this.values2 = aURL;
 } like this?

Comment: no like this `public DoctorArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomObject> objects)` each object will contain a name and an image url